# Strategy with multiple conditions true at different times

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to set up a basic strategy to trigger trades if I have an EMA crossover/under and an RSI is or was in and oversold conditions a number of periods previous

I've set up the script using pine history referencing but I'm unsure if I'm using this correctly as I'm not returning many trades.

```
strategy("RSI Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input( 14 )
vrsi = rsi(close, length)[10]

d = ema(close, 5)
e = ema(close, 10)

if (not na(vrsi))
    if (vrsi <= 30 and crossover(d,e))
        strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
    if (vrsi >= 70 and crossunder(d,e))
        strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

I was expecting to be entered into more trades as I entered a high number in the history reference. Essentially check back further for an oversold/undersold condition if I have an EMA crossover. At the moment I'm not returning many trades and the one that do, don't seem to take into around the RSI

Comment: Have you tried to plot those values? It'll be helpful to look at two plots: for short and long positions